# javascript react i18next multi languge problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to add some languge but i get some issue like Warning:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
and

```
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
            at useContext (react.development.js:1618:1)
            at useTranslation (useTranslation.js:24:1)
            at Header (Header.jsx:13:1)
            at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
            at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
            at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
            at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
            at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
            at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
            at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
```

here the code
the i18n file

```
    import i18n from "i18next";
    import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
    import languagedetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
    import translationEn from "./locale/en.json";
    import translationAR from "./locale/ar.json";
    
    const resources = {
      en: {
        translation: translationEn,
      },
      ar: {
        translation: translationAR,
      },
    };
    
    i18n
      .use(languagedetector)
      .use(initReactI18next)
      .init({
        resources,
        lng: "en",
        interpolation: {
          escapeValue: false,
        },
        react: {
          useSuspense: false,
        },
      });
    
    export default i18n;
```

and the index.js file

```
    import React, { Suspense, Component } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
    import "./index.css";
    import "./i18n";
    import App from "./App";
    
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
```

and the place where i want to change languge

```
   

     import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
        import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
        
        const Header = () => {
          const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
        
          return (
            <>
         <section className="header" id="head">
                <nav>
                  <a href="index.html">
                    <img src={tripbyddy} alt="" className="logo" />
                  </a>
                  <div className="nav-links" id="navLinks" style={style}>
                    <i className="fa fa-times" onClick={hideMenu}></i>
        
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#" target="test">
                          MAD
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img
                          src={selectedFlag}
                          id="contryflag"
                          alt=""
                          onClick={handleClick}
                        />
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <h3 id="property">List your property</h3>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="register.html">
                          <button className="btn-donate" id="register">
                            Register
                          </button>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="login.html">
                          <button className="btn-donate" id="sign">
                            Sign in
                          </button>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <i className="fa fa-bars" onClick={showMenu}></i>
                </nav>
        
                <div className="text-box">
                  <h1 id="title">embrace fresh experiences</h1>
                  <p id="mintitle">
                    Taste the flavors of the world while discovering travel deals,
                    hidden gems, and much more...
                  </p>
                </div>
              </section>
        
              <div className={`modal__wrapper ${isShown ? "" : "active"}`}>
                <div id="language" className="modal__container" ref={langref}>
                  <i className="fa fa-times" onClick={handleClick}></i>
                  <h3 id="selection">{t("title")}</h3>
```

i've tried many youtube video but the same probleme if anyone have any idea how to solve this probleme i would be so thankfull to him